# populate dropdown box in Jmeter using google chrome web driver

Tags: javascript, selenium, jmeter, chrome-web-driver

I'm struggling to populate a dropdown I can get it to select it but unsure on what to do to select the value:

```
var TitleField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('Title'))
TitleField.click()
TitleField.sendKeys(['Mr'])
```

I've seen some articles and it says you have to import a driver:

```
var driver  = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select)

Select selectObject = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id(Title)));
selectObject.selectByValue('Mr');
```

But this stops the whole test from running.

Can someone clarify what I need to do to select the dropdown value using javascript?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain more on the problem.If possible provide the link to the url or post the html element

Answer (score 1):

As per [Select JavaDoc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) it should be instantiated as:

```
Select(WebElement element)
```

So you're looking into right direction, but implementation is a little bit incorrect. The correct one would be something like:

```
var element = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id('Title'))
var select = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select(element)
select.selectByVisibleText('Mr')
```

I cannot guarantee that it will work on your environment, just in case find a complete end-to-end demo against [Select try-it-yourself at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select) below:

```
WDS.browser.get('http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select')
WDS.browser.switchTo().frame('iframeResult')
var element = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath('//select'))
var select = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select(element)
select.selectByVisibleText('Opel')
```

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) for more WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks.